# I'm having trouble working on a new react project. I've install all the necessary packages but still I can't run my server using npm start?

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting this error

> rnal command, operable program or batch file.
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936   throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'G:\Web-Development\Jumping into
> React\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }

Comment: Did you run `npm install` first?

Comment: How did you create the react project? Did you use [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) or you are doing it from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

seems, that You didin't install react-scripts, which are needed here
try to run first:

```
npm i
```

or

```
yarn
```

Btw. you should include here at last your package.json file